# click my website link on facebook android application gives net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: android, laravel, facebook

The Application is made by Laravel
my website link on Facebook application on android and iPhone casing `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` other places it's working OK no problem on my phone Firefox browser and chrome everything going fine only when try to click the link from the Fb application it gives this issue

Here is the URL to the website http://satfestival.net/

[image]

Comment: Are you experiencing this on other sites as well? I am seeing on all sites.. We do not see this issue when we pause all Ads, do you have ads on your site?

Comment: No other websites works OK no issue, and I don't have any ads on my website